# HTML zoom for full screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to zoom on a few elements so they will take whole screen on mobiles.
The code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas hidden id='textCanvas' width=400 height=300></canvas>
            <br>
    
            <div>
                <label for='place'>Place:</label><br>
                <input id='place' type='text' maxlength="15"><br>
                <label for='sun'>Sun:</label><br>
                <input id="sun" type="number"><br>
                <label for="shadow">Shadow:</label><br>
                <input id="shadow" type="number"><br>
                <br>
                <button>Send</button>
                <button>Clear screen</button>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

How it looks vs what I want:

[image] [image]

I can achieve this by setting:

```
initial-scale=2
```

But I guess that isn't resolution independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would of course be - use media responsive query - for consistency, and I am assuming you don't want the consumer to manually zoom the page to 'take whole screen on mobiles', in which media query always does the job

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        
        <style>
            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
              input {
                width: 100%;
              }
              label, input, button {
                font-size: 25px;
              }
            }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas hidden id='textCanvas' width=400 height=300></canvas>
        <br>

        <div>
            <label for='place'>Place:</label><br>
            <input id='place' type='text' maxlength="15"><br>
            <label for='sun'>Sun:</label><br>
            <input id="sun" type="number"><br>
            <label for="shadow">Shadow:</label><br>
            <input id="shadow" type="number"><br>
            <br>
            <button>Send</button>
            <button>Clear screen</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't this resolution dependent? 
Doesn't this work only for screens < 600px?
It kind of does what I want, I had to change input width to 90% (100% cut input on iPhone)
I am also worried about '25px'

Comment: 1. Isn't this resolution dependent? web apps are resolution dependent, and resolution's measurement unit is called 'pixel'(px).

Comment: 2. Doesn't this work only for screens < 600px? Yes.  Most smartphones nowadays will have a screen pixel size of <600px.  To debug for phone screens ('whole screen on mobiles' as you've requested), for chrome right click inspect --> click 'Toggle device toolbar' on the inspector, then you'll have a great selection of device-based screen sizes for you to debug (for both android and iOS).

Comment: 3. I am also worried about '25px': If you are worried about px, then use responsive sizes, such as 3rem, 15%, 15vw, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <style>
              .input {
                  width: 50%;
                  font-size: 25px;
               }

              #label  {
                 font-size: 25px;
               }
    
             .button {
                padding: 15px 32px; 
                margin: 4px 2px;
              }

             .button1 {
                font-size: 25px;
             }

        </style>

        </head>

        <body>
            <canvas hidden id='textCanvas' width=400 height=300></canvas>
            <br>
    
            <div>
                <label for='place' id="label">Place:</label><br>
                <input class="input" id='place' type='text' maxlength="15"><br>
                <label for='sun' id="label">Sun:</label><br>
                <input class="input" id="sun" type="number"><br>
                <label for="shadow" id="label">Shadow:</label><br>
                <input id="shadow" type="number" class="input"><br>
                <br>
                <button class="button button1">10px</button>
                <button class="button button1">Clear screen</button>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```